# If the user don't type for 5 sec program exits in JAVA

Tags: java, exit, reset, chronometer

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(
            "Bonjoir lol \n Convertire de Celsius à Fahrenheit tape 1 \n Convertire de Fahrenheit à Celsius tape 2 ");
   //si on ecrit rien apres 5 sc lapp doit se fermer
    Timer tm =new Timer () ;
    tm.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        int tim =5;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tim--;
            System.out.println(tim);
            if (tim==0) {  tm.cancel();
            System.exit(0);


            }
        } 


    }, 1000, 1000);
    int choix;

    try {
        choix = sc.nextInt();
    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Caractere non numerique § erreur ");
        choix = sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("D'accord");
    if (choix != 1 | choix != 2) {
        while (choix != 1 && choix != 2) {
            System.out.println("Reassayez , tapez soit 1 soit 2 !!!!!");
            try {
                choix = sc.nextInt();
            } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Caractere non numerique 1 ou 2");
                choix = sc.nextInt();
            }

        }
    }

    if (choix == 1) {
        System.out.println("Entrez la temperature en Celsius ");
        int tempc = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(celtofar(tempc) + " F°");
    } else if (choix == 2) {
        System.out.println("Entrez la temperature en Fahrenheit ");
        int tempf = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(fartocel(tempf) + "C°");
   sc.close();
    }
}


}
```

Hello , I used a chronometer when Tim=0 ,it exits the program.But how can I make the chronometer reset every time I type something in my keyboard ?? 
Hope someone can help and thanks anyway . (The chronometer is in the first lines)

Comment: Not what you asked, but the condition `(choix != 1 | choix != 2)` is _always_ true.  Perhaps you meant `&&` instead of `|`.

Comment: I didn't review my code yet , thanks mate ...